# BigQuery with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, google-bigquery

We planning to use BigQuery as the target database for an analytical application. Right now it is Postgres and the application has hibernate.

Can we use java hibernate to access BigQuery? Will, it natively supported or any limitations?

There is a driver from [Cdata](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/bigquery-jdbc-hibernate.rst), but can we use native BigQuery JBDC/ODBC drivers in Hibernate?

Comment: Hey... How did you solve this problem. We have similar requirement in our project.